# Can a JPA entity modify itself?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I have an entity

```
@Entity
class Cat {
  @Id long id;
  int lives = 9;

  public kill() {
    lives -= 1;
  }

}
```

If I am outside of a persistence context like in a POJO in my code, is there a way to make this code work in a

## ***non-hackish***

way?

Comment: that would work, except it won't be persisted, look up active record pattern

Comment: Without any intention to offend you: I recommend you reading some tutorials about how JPA works: you will read one day and will save weeks of frustating search.

Comment: @AndreiI thanks I know perfectly how JPA works, I was looking for ideas.

Comment: Then I did not understand what you meant with "make this code work" (as it does work!). Could you reformulate your question?

Comment: non-hackish way is key

Comment: What logic are you trying to achieve in that code ? If this code is not working do you have any exceptions ?

Comment: @Jay don't mind the code. It’s just an example. The point is to edit a JPA entity only by talking to that entity.

Comment: If you are outside the persistence context means its not mapped to any table... then the standalone POJO is meaningless and behaves like any other java class.... and you can't edit as JPA entity

Comment: @Jay no, if it’s outside of the persistence context it simply means that it’s a detached entity.

Comment: I doubt anyone here has understood what you are trying to ask so far. What do you mean by non-hackish? What (to you) is hackish about an entity providing methods to manipulate its fields? JPA entities are instances of Java classes, so of course they can have such methods.

Comment: @gurghet: you can modify an entity state by using _lifecycle callback methods_ as a response to a certain entity manager operation. It's a kind of self-modifying but I am not sure if I fully understand the idea behind your question.